# REGEX выбрать последнее совпадение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вот такого вида

```
AAAA E999F AAAA AAAA E999F BBB 222
```

где AAA - рандомный набор слов ( не известного количества и содержания, всегда разный ), 999 - то, что я ищу ( не известного содержания, но начинается на 'E' и заканчивается на 'F' ( определённые слова, обозначил их просто буквой ), которые мне известны ). И заканчивается строка обязательно на некое '222', которое я тоже знаю.. Т.е. мне в куче рандомного текста нужно найти слово, зная стоящие перед ним и после него слова..

Так вот, если моё 'E999F' повторяется несколько раз перед завестным '222', то как выбрать последнее его совпадение?

Вот так я нахожу первое совпадение:

```
.*?E(.*?)F.*?222
```

А нужно найти самое последнее, ближайшее в '222'..

Надеюсь, понятно изъясняюсь :3

Comment: `.*E(.*?)F.*222`

Comment: Последне - поиск "назад" включить.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew работает, но что если строка такая
`AAAA E999F AAAA AAAA E999F BBB 222 AAAA E888F AAAA AAAA E999F BBB 222 AAAA E999F AAAA AAAA E999F BBB 222`

и нужно найти все последние 999 перед каждым 222?
Т.е. не совсем-совсем последнее, а каждое последнее перед каждым 222? )

Comment: `E(\d+)F\D*222`? См. https://regex101.com/r/GK4Rec/1 Или вместо BBB может быть 123? Тогда используйте `E(\d+)F(?:(?!E\d+F).)*?222`

Comment: Ну как, работает?